# How to use JS to dynamically apply visible text to input radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently attempting to add text to each radio input field. The radio buttons appear fine. The value is set accordingly. But I can not see the text content that has been set. [Here is my expected outcome](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio). Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<form id="answers"></form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var quiz = {

  // Store questions
  questions: [
    {
      question: "What month do we celebrate the birth of Jesus?",
      answers: ["March", "September","Novemeber", "Decemeber"],
      correctAnswer: "December"
    }
  ]
}

var view = {
      showAnswers: function(){

          var answerTotal = quiz.questions[0].answers.length;

          // Loop to create radio buttons 
          for(var i = 0; i < answerTotal; i++ ){
            var answersContainer = document.getElementById('answers');
            var answersInput = document.createElement('input');
            answersInput.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
            answersInput.textContent = quiz.questions[0].answers[i];
            answersInput.value = quiz.questions[0].answers[i];
            answersContainer.appendChild(answersInput);
          }

      }

}
```

Comment: radio buttons do not have the ability to show text. you'd have to create a `span` or `div` or whatever right next to them and put the text there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value attribute of radioButton isn't the one that is visible, it's the text next to it.

This is one way of adding the text.

```js
var quiz = {

  // Store questions
  questions: [
    {
      question: "What month do we celebrate the birth of Jesus?",
      answers: ["March", "September","Novemeber", "Decemeber"],
      correctAnswer: "December"
    }
  ]
}

var view = {
      showAnswers: function(){

          var answerTotal = quiz.questions[0].answers.length;

          for(var i = 0; i < answerTotal; i++ ){
            var answersContainer = document.getElementById('answers');
            var answersInput = document.createElement('input');
            answersInput.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
            answersInput.setAttribute('name', 'question');
            answersInput.textContent = quiz.questions[0].answers[i];
            answersInput.value = quiz.questions[0].answers[i];
            answersContainer.appendChild(answersInput);
            answersContainer.innerHTML += quiz.questions[0].answers[i]+'</br>';
          }

      }

}

view.showAnswers();
```

```html
<form id="answers"></form>
```

Comment: Did you run the code yourself? This makes all the radio buttons selectable.

Comment: Yes, because i adjusted your code to answer your question, you'll have to set the name attribute to be the same in all of them. Anyway i have adjusted the answer once again.